# Query to search multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I have similar table as below:

```
Name    city    state   country
----    ----    -----   -------
Sree    mm      ap      ind
SRee    redmond ny      us
rahul   hyd     ap      ind
xxx     mm      ap      ind
abcd    mm      tn      ind
wer     dd      ap      ind
```

If I search with `mm,ap` I need to get these.

```
Name   city    state   country
----   ----    -----   -------
Sree    mm      ap      ind
xxx     mm      ap      ind
abcd    mm      tn      ind
wer     dd      ap      ind
```

If the two words match it should come first if contains in `city` second as state and third as country.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @city nvarchar(50) = 'mm',
        @state nvarchar(50) = 'ap'

Select *
From (Select *
    from YourTable
    Where city = @city or state = @state
    )z
order by Case When city = @city and state = @state Then 1
              When City = @city then 2
              Else 3
          end
```